# Aiding code review with an additional pull request

Tags: git, code-reviews, pull-requests, mistakes

I am curious how others tackle the issue of needing small, sometimes trivial changes in a pull-request. The problem crops up a lot where I work. A developer completes a task and makes a pull-request, and after some review and changes it is good to merge except for *one last detail*. Rather than ask them to once again make a change, something that takes longer to ask than do myself, I would rather make a pull-request with the desired change to their feature branch so they can simply review and we can get on with the merge. One caveat would be that my change could start a whole new, large review itself if I am mistaken about the code. On the other hand, letting small issues slip by because the code is 99.9% correct starts to pollute the code base. I feel that developers have enough distractions as is, and asking for one more `;`, or "you put all the foos here, but not this bar" in the review can be a time waster.

How do other developers go about this?

Comment: Some source control tools allow a reviewer to make code suggestions right within the PR. If yours is one of these, this would be a perfect situation for it.

Answer (score 4):

The question is: Is the pull request, as it is, acceptable? Not perfect, and not as good as you want, but acceptable?

In that case, if everyone agrees, you could accept the pull request, merge it instantly, and create a change request immediately for the outstanding changes, to be done with highest priority.

It could actually be the reviewer who makes the new changes (after all, they should know exactly what changes they wanted), and change roles.